# Javadoc for existing java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse, and say I am interested in the StreamTokenizer class, I'd like to be able to see something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) from inside Eclipse, without internet connection. How do I do that?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUDbNXTmAJg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your JDK set up correctly, you should be able to see Javadoc entries when you put your mouse over something or scroll through the auto-complete list.

Type StreamTokenizer in a Java class, make sure it's been imported at the top, then put your mouse over it to see the Javadoc for it. Same goes for methods/fields, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Java 7 Java documentation here to your desktop:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html

Then, go to Eclipse Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Select your JRE, click Edit...

Select rt.jar (This jar file contains all the runtime classes for Java), then select "Javadoc Location...", and point the URL at the zip file of your javadoc download above.

You can now access the Java 7 documentation offline in Eclipse.

Comment: This alone won't help to see the documentation from within eclipse